# C: Segmentation fault and maybe GDB is lying to me

Tags: c

Here is a C function that segfaults:

```
void compileShaders(OGL_STATE_T *state) {

    // First testing to see if I can access object properly. Correctly outputs:
    // nsHandle: 6
    state->nsHandle = 6;
    printf("nsHandle: %d\n", state->nsHandle);

    // Next testing if glCreateProgram() returns proper value. Correctly outputs:
    // glCreateProgram: 1
    printf("glCreateProgram: %d\n", glCreateProgram());


    // Then the program segfaults on the following line according to gdb
    state->nsHandle = glCreateProgram();

}
```

For the record state->nsHandle is of type GLuint and glCreateProgram() returns a GLuint so that shouldn't be my problem.

gdb says that my program segfaults on line 303 which is actually the comment line before that line. I don't know if that actually matters.

Is gdb lying to me? How do I debug this?

**EDIT:**

Turned off optimizations (-O3) and now it's working. If somebody could explain why that would be great though.

**EDIT 2:**
For the purpose of the comments, here's a watered down version of the important components:

```
typedef struct {
    GLuint nsHandle;
} OGL_STATE_T;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    OGL_STATE_T _state, *state=&_state;
    compileShaders(state);
}
```

**EDIT 3:**
Here's a test I did:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    OGL_STATE_T _state, *state=&_state;

    // Assign value and try to print it in other function
    state->nsHandle = 5;

    compileShaders(state);

}

void compileShaders(OGL_STATE_T *state) {

    // Test to see if the first call to state is getting optimized out
    // Correctly outputs:
    // nsHandle (At entry): 5
    printf("nsHandle (At entry): %d\n", state->nsHandle);

}
```

Not sure if that helps anything or if the compiler would actually optimize the value from the main function.

**EDIT 4:**
Printed out pointer address in main and compileShaders and everything matches. So I'm gonna assume it's segfaulting somewhere else and gdb is lying to me about which line is actually causing it.

Comment: What is your compile line?

Comment: Was on IRC channel and buddy pointed out to turn off optimizations. I did and it works now. I'd like to understand the why of it though.

Comment: What version of `gcc` are you using? I think it is a compiler bug to produce different results with and without optimization, and I have observed this in the past.

Comment: Turning off optimizations doesn't fix the problem, only hide it. Your code still has a bug, and it could manifest itself in unknown ways at unknown times.

Comment: Are you using any threading?

Comment: @merlin2011 gcc 4.8.2 20131219 (prerelease) on a ARM7 processor

Comment: @merlin2011: If a program contains undefined behavior, there are no requirements that the code produce the same results on different optimization levels. In fact, there are no requirements of what the code does at all. Optimization is only required not to change the program's behavior if the program contains no undefined behavior - roughly speaking, if the program is correct.

Comment: `state` is a pointer passed into the function - I'm guessing that the pointer is pointing to unallocated memory. You should show how the pointer passed to `compileShaders()` is initialized.

Comment: @user2357112, Good point. Agreed.

Comment: @MichaelBurr View edit 2 and notice it shouldn't be a problem. The struct should be initialized properly.

Comment: @ReX357: Why write `OGL_STATE_T _state, *state=_state;
    compileShaders(state);` instead of `OGL_STATE_T _state;
    compileShaders(&_state);`?

Comment: @DCoder Sorry original code had it. I just retyped it and forgot the ampersand. Fixed it in the post.

Comment: @AndyG Sorry fixed my post, I forgot the ampersand but the real code is written with it *state=&_state;

Comment: @ReX357: GDB isn't human and it has no motive to lie to you!

Comment: @legends2k Are you sure about that? I think it's out to get me.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that implies you create a valid [OpenGL context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Context). You can't call OpenGL without first creating a context.

Comment: @unwind This code is a watered down test case to isolate the problem. The problem is not OpenGL.

Comment: As written in the last answer, the OP did not give enough information to solve the original question and started another question instead of improving this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting a new thread with more relevant information and somebody found the answer. New thread is here:

[GCC: Segmentation fault and debugging program that only crashes when optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876433/gcc-segmentation-fault-and-debugging-program-that-only-crashes-when-optimized/22876481#22876481)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be guesswork based on what you have, but with optimization on this line:

```
state->nsHandle = 6;
printf("nsHandle: %d\n", state->nsHandle);
```

is probably optimized to just

```
printf("nsHandle: 6\n");
```

So the first access to `state` is where the segfault is. With optimization on GDB can report odd line numbers for where the issue is because the running code may no longer map cleanly to source code lines as you can see from the example above.

As mentioned in the comments, `state` is almost certainly not initialized. Some other difference in the optimized code is causing it to point to an invalid memory area whereas the non-optimized code it's pointing somewhere valid.

This might happen if you're doing something with pointers directly that prevents the optimizer from 'seeing' that a given variable is used.

A sanity check would be useful to check that `state != 0` but it'll not help if it's non-zero but invalid.

You'd need to post the calling code for anyone to tell you more. However, you asked how to debug it -- I would print (or use GDB to view) the value of `state` when that function is entered, I imagine it will be vastly different in optimized and non-optimized versions. Then track back to the function call to work out why that's the case.

**EDIT**

You posted the calling code -- that should be fine. Are you getting warnings when compiling (turn all the warnings on with `-Wall`). In any case my advice about printing the value of `state` in different scenarios still stands.

*(removed comment about adding & since you edited the question again)*

Comment: Please have a look at Edit 3. I've tried to assign in main and print in compileShaders and I'm getting the correct value. Not sure if that would get optimized between the 2 functions.

Comment: Also I compile with -Wall and I do not get any warnings. I have also tried testing state==NULL and printing something if that evaluates to true but it doesn't evaluate to true. So I'm gonna assume it might have an invalid address when code is optimized?

Comment: Don't print the value of `state->nsHandle`, print the actual value of 'state'. Both in the main function and the called function -- of course that may change the behavior of the optimizer so perhaps you're better off printing the value in GDB inside the function call. Alternatively you can disassembly the code and look at the assembly file -- compare differences between the optimized and non-optimized version.

Comment: Yeah just tried that. Printed from main and compileShaders and both pointers point to the same address. I'm gonna look down a few lines in compileShaders and see if there's anything else that could cause undefined behaviors.

Comment: One other option is, with the original code, try and get a breakpoint in GDB *just before* the segfault and examine the variables that are being used for anything suspicious. It is possible it's a compiler bug as well, you could try with a different compiler version.

Comment: Another idea, are both functions in the same file? If they're in different files are you sure they're seeing the same version of the definition of `OGL_STATE_T` -- perhaps they're managing to include different headers or in a different order.

Comment: Functions are in different files but struct definition is in header file that is included in both files.

Comment: And about the previous comment to that, the original code does not segfault. Only when optimized.

Comment: I meant GDB the optimized version of the code, the line numbers will be screwy but it should still give you some idea of where the issue is. Apart from that I'm out of ideas for the moment.

Comment: SpaceDog Thank you very much for taking the time to walk me through this. At least I got to try a whole bunch of steps I wouldn't of thought of trying right away.

Answer (score 1):

When you optimize your program, there is no more 1:1 mapping between source lines and emmitted code. 
Typically, the compiler will reorder the code to be more efficient for your CPU, or will inline function call, etc...

This code is wrong:

```
*state=_state
```

It should be:

```
*state=&_state
```

Well, you edited your post, so ignore the above fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the NULL condition before de-referencing the pointer or reading it. If the values you pass are NULL or if the values stored are NULL then you will hit segfault without performing any checks.

FYI: GDB Can't Lie !